# Converting date to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, date

I have a date in string form and input timeformat(ex: hh:mm tt). I want to convert date to dateime string. Below is my code :

```
    string inputDate = "01/02/11";
    string inputTimeFormat = "hh:mm tt";

    Regex rgx1 = new Regex("tt");
    string time1 = rgx1.Replace(inputTimeFormat, "AM");
    Regex rgx = new Regex("[^ :AM]");
    string time = rgx.Replace(time1, "0");
    string dateTime = string.Format("{0} {1}", inputDate, time);
    //output: 01/02/11 00:00 AM
```

Right now it is giving output in datetime string format, Is there any better way of doing the same?

EDIT: I need datetime in string format here and after that I can apply Datetime.TryParseExact

Comment: Your edit is incorrect.  You can call `TryParseExact` right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `DateTime` type:

```
DateTime.Parse("01/02/11").ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Comment: That will parse differently in the UK than in the US, though.  This might be what he wants, or he might want .ParseExact() with an explicit format string for the date as well.

Comment: This will give time and not datetime.

Comment: @Rocky: Then you need to change the format string.  eg, `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt"`

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.ParseExact('your date string', format, culture)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Parse doesn't use a format as second argument, but a IFormatProvider

Comment: Oops sorry, I mean ParseExact